# Can Telegram bot detect a new member joining a channel event?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I have a Telegram bot and I set this bot as admin of a channel. Now, when a new user ordinarily joins a channel (not a group) there is no message on the channel and no message we could get with `getUpdates` method. Is it technically possible to post a message saying “A new user has joined the channel” - and this traps the “new member” event? Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you **can't** check if user joined a channel or not via Telegram bot API for now. maybe in the future you can.

But you can do it for groups or super groups here :

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message find `new_chat_members`

These are also useful :

[Telegram Bot Event When Users Join To Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38324448/7903663)

[How to get channel updates with Telegram robot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736324/7903663)

**Update :**

> But a TG bot api with admin rights can see all its members. So even if the api doesn’t support it, it can track a count and see if it increases and then know that a new member joined. Correct? I don’t need to know exactly WHICH new member joined but just know a new one joined to share a welcome message

Yes you can use `getChatMembersCount`. Here is information from this [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) :

> `getChatMembersCount`: Use this method to get the number of members in a chat. Returns Int on success.

and also can use `getChatMember` and [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) is some information :

> `getChatMember:` Use this method to get information about a member of a chat. Returns a ChatMember object on success.

Comment: But a TG bot api with admin rights can see all its members. So even if the api doesn’t support it, it can track a count and see if it increases and then know that a new member joined. Correct? I don’t need to know exactly WHICH new member joined but just know a new one joined to share a welcome message

Comment: Get count have some problem. If an user leave a group an then another sig in, the number is the same and this logic fail. I don't know why telegram makes this management so difficult

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can detect a new member joining:

```
async def greet_chat_members(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
"""Greets new users in chats and announces when someone leaves"""
result = extract_status_change(update.chat_member)
if result is None:
    return

was_member, is_member = result
cause_name = update.chat_member.from_user.mention_html()
member_name = update.chat_member.new_chat_member.user.mention_html()

if not was_member and is_member:
    await update.effective_chat.send_message(
        f"{member_name} was added by {cause_name}. Welcome!",
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
    )
elif was_member and not is_member:
    await update.effective_chat.send_message(
        f"{member_name} is no longer with us. Thanks a lot, {cause_name} ...",
        parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML,
    )
```

for more detail visit [this link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/chatmemberbot.py);